# How can I use the same fragment\instance more than one place

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 places with the same Fragment, and I want that all the 3 Fragments will be the same (Every change in one of the Fragments will change the others), How can I use the same fragment\instance?

Comment: You cannot do that. You have to synchronize the state of the fragments by yourself.

Comment: So send a broadcast message to the rest of the Fragments using LocalBroadcastManager can be a good solution?

Comment: For example. Or any other event bus. I would consider RX though.

Answer (score 0):

Please, look here - [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/).

Otto is an event bus designed to decouple different parts of your application while still allowing them to communicate efficiently.

Forked from Guava, Otto adds unique functionality to an already refined event bus as well as specializing it to the Android platform.

Comment: And it's deprecated with the suggestion to use RX.

Comment: @tynn This  issue not about rx, and therefore the example of Otto relevant. If the topicaster would have been familiar with RxAndroid, the question would not be asked. If you wish, you can apply and RxBus and other libs... Rx - not always the best solution...